# Java: Poisson-based point process constrained in a small region

Tags: java, processing, simulation, poisson

While simulating a random point process based on Poisson distribution that contains 1000 dots; they all appear to occupy a small region in the center of the window.

I used Donald Knuth inverse sampling algorithm to implement the Poisson-based pseudo-random number generator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables

Lambda value (aka the success rate) was set to window_dimension/2, and obtained this result (screenshot)

[image: Point-process using poisson-based pseudo-random generator]

Code:

```
public double getPoisson(double lambda) {//250
    double L = Math.exp(-lambda);
    double p = 1d;
    int k = 0;
    do {
        k++;
        p *= Math.random();
    } while (p > L);

    return k-1;
}
```

`

Comment: We don't want to see the full code. But we need to see enough code to see the problem. In other words, please narrow your problem down to a [mcve] and post that. Have you tried debugging your code? What parameters have you tried tweaking already? What exactly did you expect this code to do instead?

Comment: I varied the value of Lambda (too small induces no visible change on the window, same with big values). I will provide the Class relative to this method

Comment: Like I said, we need to see a [mcve]. We don't want to just see the class relative to this method. You should try to create a **minimal** program that contains as few lines as possible, but that we can copy and paste onto our own machines to see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Also note that you've tagged this with both [tag:processing] and [tag:java], which tends to attract a lot of downvotes from Java developers who aren't familiar with Processing. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be annoying, but the class you just posted doesn't really tell us much. We need to see how the points are getting their locations, and how they're being drawn. Please try to narrow it down to an MCVE instead of posting your whole project.

Comment: Added relative classes (Point, Poisson and the main class), it's a basic program, couldn't shrink it more.

Comment: Can I take a step back and ask you what your end goal is?

Comment: Comparison between the build-in RRNG algorithm and Poisson-based PRNG in the sense that which one is to be considered more random.

Comment: @Jiru random means not predictable with certainty.  Both are random, it's a binary state--you either are or are not predictable with certainty.  Asking which is more random is like asking "which is more 3-d, a sphere or a cube?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is with what you think the output should be, because the program seems to be generating pretty much what you asked.  A [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with a rate of 500 will have both its expected value and its variance equal to 500, and for large values of λ it's pretty symmetric and bell-shaped.  Taken together that all means the standard deviation is `sqrt(500)`, which is slightly less than 22.4, so you should expect about 95% of your incomes to be 500±45, which looks like what you're getting.

With your subsequent edit saying (in a comment) that λ=250, the results behave similarly.  The likely range of outcomes in each dimension is 250±31, still clustering to the center.

It's easy to confirm my explanation by creating Poisson random variates with a standard deviation such that ±3σ span your plot area.
You need a larger variance/standard deviation to increase the spread of outcomes across your window.  To demo this, I went with a Poisson(6400)—which has a standard deviation of 80—and subtracted 6150 to give the result a mean of 250.  The overwhelming majority of values will therefore fall between 0 and 500.  I generated 1000 independent pairs of values and plotted them using the JMP statistics package, and here are the results:

[image: Plot of pairs of (Poisson(6400)-6150) random variates]

and just for jollies, here's a plot of independent pairs of Normal(250, 80)'s:

[image]

They look pretty darn similar, don't they?

To reiterate, there's nothing wrong with the Poisson algorithm you used.  It's doing exactly what you told it to do, even if that's not what you expected the results to look like.

---

### Addendum

Since you don't believe that [Poisson converges to Gaussian as lambda grows](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/UDR.html), here's some direct evidence for your specific case, again generated with JMP:

[image: Histogram and normal distribution fit results for Poisson(250)]

On the left is a histogram of 1000 randomly generated Poisson(250) values.  Note the well-formed bell shape.  I had JMP select the best continuous distribution fit based on [AIC (Aikaike Information Criterion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion).  It selected normality as the best possible fit, with the diagnostics on the right and the resulting density plot in red superimposed on the histogram.  The results pretty much speak for themselves.

Comment: Bell-shaped curves are attributed to Normal Gaussian Distribution, the Poisson distribution has a different curve. Although your explanation sounds accurate, it's not true.

Comment: This JMP must be a thing to plot such graph with Lambda = 6400! Unfortunately I couldn't test the above code for lambda >~700 as the MIN double value Java can hold is 2^(-1074).
Thanks tough.

Comment: [JMP](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/home.html) is a commercial stats software package by the SAS corporation.  Many people like R these days because it's free, but SAS has a very solid reputation in the statistics community, and have been around for over 40 years.